# Transitioning menu by clicking on the 'hamburger' icon in mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to frontend development and have been stuck on this particular transitioning of an element when clicking on another element.

In the mobile version of my code, I would like to click on the 'hamburger' icon on the top right, which would trigger the menu opening, and that menu should start at a width of 40% and I want it to transition to 80% over 3s.
So when I click on the 'hr-lines' class, the ul menu would transition from 40% to 80% width.

I have not learned the JS libraries yet, so I am using vanilla JS for the click events.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okahn00/eq20fk37/39/

The code can also be found below:

```js
      const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
      const exitBtn = document.getElementById("exit");
      const hrLines = document.querySelector(".hr-lines");
      const ul = document.querySelector(
        "ul"
      ); /*This element should be transitioned.*/

      /*When the 3 lines are clicked:*/
      hrLines.addEventListener("click", function () {
        nav.classList.toggle("hide-mobile"); /*Reveals nav menu*/
        exitBtn.classList.toggle(
          "hide-mobile"
        ); /*Reveals the exit button when 3 lines are clicked on*/
        hrLines.classList.toggle("hide-mobile");
      });

      /*When exit button is clicked:*/
      exitBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        nav.classList.toggle("hide-mobile"); /*Removes nav menu*/
        exit.classList.toggle("hide-mobile"); /*Removes the exit button*/
        hrLines.classList.toggle("hide-mobile"); /*Reveals the 3 lines*/
      });
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }

  body {
    background-color: rgb(126, 115, 228);
  }

  ul {
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 206px;
    bottom: 107px;
  }

  /*styles the 3 lines*/
  hr {
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /*hamburger icon*/
  .hr-lines {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 45px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .exit-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    left: 305px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0 10px 8px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
    <span class="exit-btn hide-mobile" id="exit">x</span>

    <div class="hr-lines">
      <hr />
      <hr />
      <hr />
    </div>

    <nav class="hide-mobile">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds not complicated. You can look for javascript transition animation and click events.